# Unknown Texas Coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, united-states

Working with point data from Texas and am unfamiliar with what coordinate system it's using. Unfortunately, I am on a work computer which doesn't allow me to do much without admin privileges, so downloading and running Projectionuesser isn't a possibility at this moment.

Below is some examples of the point data:

2127838.753,    13709652.5

2061615.337,    13718121.64

2061615.337,    13718121.64

These points should all be in the San Antonio area of Texas.

Comment: NAD83 (or a variant like HARN, 2011, etc.) State Plane Texas South Central zone, using US survey feet. How to check this in ArcGIS? Add some known data to a new map. Set the data frame's coordsys to a possible coordsys. See if the coordinate values match the "unknown" data coordinate values.

Comment: @mkennedy ?That worked! Thanks for that aswell as help on future issues like this.